# Can we make a hidden field readonly

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of hidden fields on my web page and it contains information to it, which i use some manipulation on latter stage.
But these hidden field are directly access to the user and it can be modified by inspect element from browser.

can i make a hidden field read only. if not then how to prevent it?

Any better option to store data on web page for manipulation. By store in global variable. Can also  global variable editable by browser console or not.

Comment: for example what kind of information ?

Comment: You can't prevent anything. Imagine you're a web server. You send an HTML page (including JavaScript code) to me, the client. Then I can do whatever I want with it. Once you send me the data, you've lost all control over it.

Comment: product information like expdate, mrp, rate etc

Comment: Yes ,All data on the webpage can edit ! But it doesn't matter ,coz you store your data on server !

Comment: You can set a `readonly` attribute on the input but like the answerers say it isn't tamper proof.

Answer (score 1):

No, anything that is on the web page or in JavaScript on the client is manipulable by the user. The only ways to prevent it is to encrypt it such that it can only be manipulated on the server, or just don't send it to the client and use it only on the server.

Comment: can you describe it.

Comment: Can I describe what?

Comment: so you want to say if i have a product and want to calculate total mrp of x no of products then every time i have to fetch it from server

Comment: Only if you care about the answer being correct and unmodified.  If you're doing it for the user experience, then you can do it on the client. But you don't want to trust that number when you process an order on the server.

Comment: Also note that if a user modifies these numbers, it only affects their view unless you allow that change to persist to the server.

Comment: As I said, you can't prevent them from modifying values in their own browser. All you can do is limit the impact of that.

Answer (score 0):

Better to store the information as session variables even if the user changes the values it will not reflect in the backend